# How do I return a reversed iterator?

Tags: rust

I was writing some code where I want to use an iterator, or its reversed version depending on a flag, but the straightforward code gives an error

```
pub fn eggs<I,T>(iter:I)->Box<dyn Iterator<Item=T>>
where I:Iterator<Item=T>+DoubleEndedIterator
{
    Box::new(iter.rev())
}

pub fn bacon<I,T>(iter:I, reverse:bool) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item=T>>
    where I:Iterator<Item=T>+DoubleEndedIterator
{
    if reverse {
        Box::new(iter.rev())
    } else {
        Box::new(iter)
    }

}

fn main()
{
    let pants:String = "pants".into();
    eggs(pants.chars());
}
```

fails to compile:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `I` may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
2 | pub fn eggs<I,T>(iter:I)->Box<dyn Iterator<Item=T>>
  |             - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `I: 'static`
...
5 |     Box::new(iter.rev())
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `Rev<I>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

With my limited understanding of Rust, I'm not sure where those lifetime bounds are coming from.  There aren't any on the `Iterator` trait, or the `Rev` struct, and the parameter is being moved.

What is the proper way to declare these sorts of functions given that `'static` isn't really an option.

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=%0Apub%20fn%20eggs%3CI%2CT%3E(iter%3AI)-%3EBox%3Cdyn%20Iterator%3CItem%3DT%3E%3E%0Awhere%20I%3AIterator%3CItem%3DT%3E%2BDoubleEndedIterator%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Anew(iter.rev())%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20fn%20bacon%3CI%2CT%3E(iter%3AI%2C%20reverse%3Abool)%20-%3E%20Box%3Cdyn%20Iterator%3CItem%3DT%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20where%20I%3AIterator%3CItem%3DT%3E%2BDoubleEndedIterator%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20reverse%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Anew(iter.rev())%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Anew(iter)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20pants%3AString%20%3D%20%22pants%22.into()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20eggs(pants.chars())%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: You might also want to look at the [either](https://crates.io/crates/either) crate instead of boxing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't have to do with `.rev()` at all, but with returning `Box<dyn Iterator>`:

```rust
// error[E0310]: the parameter type `I` may not live long enough
fn boxed_iter<I, T>(iter: I) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = T>>
//            - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `I: 'static`
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    Box::new(iter)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `I` will meet its required lifetime bounds
}
```

The reason for this is that trait objects like `Box<dyn Trait>` have an implicit `'static` lifetime if not specified. So when the compiler tries to cast `Box<I>` to `Box<dyn Iterator>`, it fails if `I` is does not also have a `'static` lifetime. (There are some more specific rules if the trait contains lifetimes itself; you can read about those in more detail [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes).)

If you instead want a shorter lifetime, you need to specify it explicitly as `Box<dyn 'a + Trait>`. So for example:

```rust
fn boxed_iter<'a, I, T>(iter: I) -> Box<dyn 'a + Iterator<Item = T>>
where
    I: 'a + Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    Box::new(iter)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Frxstrem's answer is excellent. I just want to add that, if you know that the return value of your function has a specific concrete type, you can use the special [impl trait syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/impl_trait.html).

In the case of your `eggs` function, the return type is probably something like `Rev<I>`. That type, on its own, isn't very illuminating, but we know that such a type *exists* and the only thing we care about is that it's an iterator, so we can write

```
pub fn eggs<I,T>(iter:I) -> impl Iterator<Item=T> + DoubleEndedIterator
where I: Iterator<Item=T> + DoubleEndedIterator {
  iter.rev()
}
```

Now the compiler still understands that there is a single concrete type and will act accordingly (no need to box the value or have dynamic dispatch), but we as the programmers still only have to care about the `Iterator` and `DoubleEndedIterator` aspects of it. Zero-cost abstraction at its finest.

Your `bacon` function can't benefit from this, as it could return either an `I` or a `Rev<I>` depending on input, so the dynamic dispatch is actually necessary. In that case, you'll need to follow Frxstrem's answer to correctly box your iterator.